# Where does アフレコ come from?

Tags: etymology, katakana

I looked for the meaning of アフレコ in [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B3) and after the meaning (dubbing) it says "Abbreviation, Wasei, word made in Japan". So since the word apparently it doesnt come from a foreign language, and since the dubbing process is a little over 100 years old, where does the word アフレコ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アフレコ is an abbreviation of "after recording" (source: 三省堂 スーパー大辞林).

"wasei" literally means "Japanese-made". It's a term used to describe words that were made in Japan, despite being made out of foreign words. For example, "wasei eigo" means "Japanese-made English". <s>Another famous example of wasei eigo is "salaryman", which despite seeming like an English word, is only used in Japan.</s> (Apparently not quite! See Eiríkr's comment.)

Comment: _Sararīman_ is often trotted out as _wasei eigo_.  However, it does in fact derive from regular English, albeit dated English that is no longer in current use: the phrase "salaried man".  See [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22salaried+man%22), for instance, displaying numerous hits from earlier in the 1900s.  See also [the Daijirin entry at Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3), displaying the derivation from this same English phrase.

Comment: I have a feeling that if the Japanese word had retained the -ied pronunciation it wouldn't be regarded by people as wasei-eigo. You can't convert the Japanese as it is back into English and have it be considered acceptable to most speakers.

Comment: @Leebo, I think you're right about that, but the -ied pronuciation would be much more awkward in Japanese... sarariidoman.... it's not hard to see why they dropped it to make sarariiman